# Where is JavaVirtualMachine installed on Mac?

Tags: java, jvm

I installed jvm 8 (8u45) on Mac 10.10, but running ./java_home -v 1.8 still get Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".

java_home finds JVM 1.6 under path /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home, but there's nothing but 1.6. Where can I find jvm 8 on mac?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Solved: I solved it by installing jdk 8u45.

Comment: where does the DMG installer install 8u45 though?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've solved the issue by installing the JDK, but what probably happened initially was that you installed the JRE. You might find that installation at `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/`, which you could check with

`/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version`